# Checking if a column has the same values if the other column has the same value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two string columns in a Pandas dataframe.
Column1 has thousands of different values, but column2 has one of five strings, say A, B, C, D, and E.

What I would like to check is if column2 has the same value if the values are same in column1 and identify the index of the row if they are diffent.

```
idx  col1  col2
1    X     A
2    Y     B
3    Y     B
4    X     A
5    Z     C
6    X     B
```

In the above, rows 2 and 3 has the same values in column1 and the values in column are the same. So it is okay.
For rows 1, 4, and 6, it is commonly X in column A but the values in column2 are different (A, A, and B).

I need to check the Pandas dataframe meets this requirement, and identify the rows 1, 4, and 6 or the value X if there is one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) for get rows not number of unique values per groups equal `1`:

```
df1 = df[df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform('nunique').ne(1)]
print (df1)
   idx col1 col2
0    1    X    A
3    4    X    A
5    6    X    B
```

Or for get values of column `col1` use [`DataFrameGroupBy.nunique`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.nunique.html) with filter indices of `Series`:

```
s = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].nunique()
vals = s.index[s.ne(1)].tolist()
print (vals)
['X']
```